# Enable multilingual on SharePoint 2007 Site Collection

Tags: variations, multilingual

I have an internet SharePoint 2007 (MOSS) portal and I want to enable multilingual for it, what is the best practice?

Considering I have tried to enable variation and it did work on the new content but I want it to copy the old content (date before I enable variation).

Also my site does not contains publishing page only and I read that this is a limitation on variations; it does work only on the pages http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628966.aspx#limitations

I have thought of creating a new site collection inside the parent then restore a copy of the site collection then from the content database change the langid but this is a bad behavior to modify the content DB the start to rename (update) all the content!! seems the easiest and fastest solution but with a very bad (not recommended change in the content DB)

Can anyone guide me what the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

1 - You need to install the language packs for all the languages do you want to support

2 - You must create a site-collection for all these languages (ex: en-us, it-it, ...)

3 - You need to create and deploy resources for these languages

4 - You must use the resources on your code.

Comment: You only need to create one site collection as the source. Variations will create a subsite for each variation target you define.